# How soon can I run the Cayo Perico heist?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

Starting with a brand new level 0 account, how soon can I go into the heist ? Is it just the submarine I'd need to buy, or are there any other prerequisites ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the heists in GTA Online can be started at any level as long as you have completed the tutorials and you buy the required property:

- The Fleeca Job
- The Prison Break
- The Humane labs Raid
- Series A Funding
- The Pacific Standard Job

  - Any High End Apartment
- The Doomsday Heist: The Data Breaches
- The Doomsday Heist: The Bogdan Problem
- The Doomsday Heist: The Doomsday Scenario

  - Any Facility
- The Diamond Casino Heist: Silent & Sneaky
- The Diamond Casino Heist: Aggressive
- The Diamond Casino Heist: The Big Con

  - Any Arcade
- The Cayo Perico Heist

  - The Kosatka